# Want to create mouse clicks on a window with java

Tags: java

I want to create java code which will stimulate a mouse click on any window of a windows OS application - eg browser, word etc.

Can someone suggest how I can begin ? I don't know which API's are needed for this.
I also need to know if this is a very complex task and will require more than just 
core concepts of Java.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: java.awt.Robot should cover it: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html

Comment: @JonHulka - thanks. i was suspecting that they would not have made a class for this

Comment: @JonHulka - looks like java may not be the best language to do this task, as  suggested by -hovercraftfullofeels. Have you used robot before for a similar task ? Was it too complicated and clunky ?

Comment: I have never actually done this. Considering that you want to interact with the operating system, it might be difficult to get Java working without some JNI which would pretty much defeat the purpose of using Java in the first place. If you were just interacting with a web page, then a Java/javascript combination would work nicely.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The class you would want to use for this task is the `Robot` class: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html

It may require more knowledge than the core concepts (depending on what you consider core), but Java is a good language to deal with this kind of thing.

Depending on what you seek to do with this knowledge, this may end up a very complex task. For example, if you sought to click on a specific button on the screen, you would need some way to analyze the screen (a very hard task). If you know where every button is already, you just move to the x, y location and cause a click to occur.

Comment: One of my objectives is also to click repeatedly on a particular part of a screen at regular intervals. Any suggestions/warnings before I begin making my "clicker" ?

Comment: @FirstNameLastName: If you're trying to create a "bot" with Java, don't. It's actually a terrible language for this sort of program since it of necessity is very far removed from the native platform, the operating system.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels - would python be better then ?

Comment: @FirstNameLastName: You've not told us -- what is it you are trying to create in the first place?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels - code which will click a button in a webpage or a desktop (windows) application.

Comment: I would use AutoIt or C or C++ myself for something like this.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels - please tell me why you prefer C, C++ or autolt (wow ! what is that) over java.

Comment: I have to disagree with HovercraftFullOfEels, C or C++ would not be a good option (though I haven't used AutoIt). Java lends itself much better to Event Driven Programming than C and C++. There are many times I would choose C and C++ over Java (most times), but, for ease of use in event driven programming, definitely go Java.

Comment: @FirstNameLastName: it's much easier to make operating system calls if you use a language that allows you to get close to the operating system. Java is fine for simple clicking, but if you need true dynamic interaction with the program that you're driving, then you must be able to ascertain the driven program's state. This is much easier achieved if you can directly query the program for this through the OS rather than use a brittle kludge such as extracting images.

Comment: @banshee_walk_sly - can you tell me why java is easier than c, c++ for event driven programming ? Also, why it may be better for my purposes ?

Comment: In response to Hovercraft Full Of Eels: the OP is asking for clicking functionality, and has made no indications that they need to query the program's state or to have deep interaction with the clicked program.

In response to FirstName LastName: Java provides a large number of built-in libraries with thorough documentation. Another language may be a better option for true dynamic interaction, but Java's Object-Orientation and wealth of libraries make it the better choice in my opinion.

Comment: I can't disagree, but of course it will all depend on what the original poster desires. 1+